# Regex to find all fixed length numbers in a bigger number

Tags: java, regex

I want to match all fixed length numbers, in another and bigger number. For example; if my number is

```
123456
```

i want to obtain `123`, `234`, `345`, `456`. I am not looking for any other possible combination like `135` or `654`. How can I achieve this?

I simply tried pattern `\d{3}` but it returned me just `123`.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex to grab all the 3 digit numbers using captured groups:

```
(?=(\d{3}))
```

Lookahead is zero-width assertion giving us the ability to lookahead the 3 digit numbers without actually moving the internal regex pointer.

In java use:

```
"(?=(\\d{3}))"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yV1nA9/1)

Comment: Nice answer - I'd add that you need to back-reference group index 1 though for clarity.

Comment: Yes indeed get `matcher.group(1)` in a `while(matcher.find())` loop.

Comment: Yes this is precisely what I have been looking for. Thank you :)